# jQuery scroll to sections in button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problem to scroll in each section separately by using the same button. If I click for the first time, this should send me to section2, and then If i click again the same button, this should send me to section3

I have tried to make it by every click to scroll 500px to bottom or something like that but seems that this is not good solution for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.scroller').click(function() {

    var fuller = $(this).closest('.fullscreen').next(),
      section = $(this).closest('.section');

    section.animate({
      scrollTop: section.scrollTop() + fuller.offset().top
    }, 700);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <a href=# class="scroller">Scroll</>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="section1">Content2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="half-screen">
      <div class="s">Content 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
    <span>
            <div class="">Content 3</div>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="section4">
    <div class="half-screen">
      <div class="s">Content 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This kind of code send me just to the section2 and then doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure `scrollTop: section.scrollTop()` is correct? shouldn't this be something like `section.offset().top` like for the fuller?

Comment: Not related: Inline elements cannot contain block level elements (`<span><div></div></span>`).

Comment: Do u want the button for all the section?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yes, this is the issue, because I need to use one button for all sections.

Comment: From where i have to add the button?

Comment: button should be somewhere in the top, is fixed

Comment: there is no "scroller" in your html-code

Comment: Yea, I edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `counter` to achieve your task. When the button is clicked, we check if `counter` hasn't reached the sections (those to be scrolled to) length (the number of the sections in the page), scroll to the next section and increment the `counter` otherwise scroll to the first section and assign 0 to the counter so we can click again and have the same functionality.

But before digging into the code (logic), I have some points to talk about :

- your `HTML` is semantically wrong : an `inline` level element (a `span` in your case) can't host `block` level elements (a `div` in your case).
- the button (the `a.scroller` element) is the only one component that has the scrolling functionality, select it (in `jQuery`) based on it's `ID` (we'll give it one) seems more better than a `class` (that's faster as `jQuery` will use the native `getElementByID` to select the element, you can read the `jQuery` code and get how it does the selecting job).
- as I tried to say, `classes` are used to select more than one element in the page. The sections (to be scrolled to) should have a common `class` (also to be used in `jQuery`).

So building on those points above, I prepared a demo example for you in which you can extend to achieve your desired end results. Also, the example has a wealth of helpful comments to help you when reading the code.

```js
$(() => {
  /**
  * select the main elements having affect in the process.
  * sections: the sections to be scrolled to.
  * btn: the "a" element that that triggers the scrolling effect.
  * idx: the counter that used to distinguish which section should we scroll to. 
  **/
  let sections = $('.scroll-to'),
    btn = $("#scroller"),
    idx = 1;
  /** adding the click listener to the "a" element **/
  btn.on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); /** preventing the jump to top (and adding "#" to the URL) **/
    idx >= sections.length && (idx = 0); /** if the counter reaches the number of the section in the page we must decrement it to 0 **/
    /** scroll effect: the "body" and the "html" elements should scroll not a section but the scroll destination is based on the section with the index "idx" offset from the top of the page (all the page not only the viewport) **/
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(sections[idx++]).offset().top
    }, 700);
  });
});
```

```css
/** basic styling for the demo purposes and to allow the scroll effect to be seen **/

.scroll-to {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#scroller {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px -1px rgba(18, 18, 18, .6);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- no "span" elements having "div" ones which is semantically wrong -->

<!-- the sections to be scrolled to have a common class "scroll-to" which will be used to select all these section in "jQuery" -->

<!-- the "a" element now have an ID of "scroller" to select it rapidly with "jQuery" -->

<div class="section">
  <a href="#" id="scroller">Scroll</a>
  <div class="scroll-to fullscreen">
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-to section2">
    <div class="half-screen">
      <div class="s">Content 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-to section3">
    Content 3
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-to section4">
    <div class="half-screen">
      <div class="s">Content 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm here for any clarifications.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Yes this is the result what I want. Thanks

Comment: @alar you're welcome ! Feel free to ask about any further clarifications.